# image input to neural networks

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am doing figure extractor from scanned documents. using 1100x850 images. we use 44x34 grids of image. so that last layer will be 1496 fully connected layer.
 label is 44x34 BINARY array which is 1 for figure rigion and 0 for non figure region. i.e if figure falls within (top right) (x,y)=(0,0) (bottom left) (x,y)=(50,50) then bin array has 1 at (0,0) (0,1) and (1,0) (1,1) these positions and rest 0s. so i have buit a neural network model. following is the structure.

```
conv(5,2,48)
maxpool(3,2)
conv(5,2,96)
maxpool(3,2)
conv(5,2,96)
maxpool(3,2)
FC-1496
```

The notation conv(k,d, n) denotes a convolutional layer with n filters, each of size k × k, applied with a shift of d pixels; maxpool(k, d) denotes a downsampling operation over k×k windows, applied with a shift of d pixels. FC-1496 refers to the final fully connected
layer which connects the hidden units from the previous layers to the 1496 output units (we have 1496 units for a 44x34 grid).

So my question is how to feed input ( images and labels (array) ) to this model using keras and tensor flow.

here is the model code

```
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten


xtrain=#image of 850*1100 for 10 images 10 850*1100
xtest=#binary array of size 1496 for 10 images size is 10*1496

# initialize the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(48, 5, 2, input_shape=(1100, 850, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2))

model.add(Conv2D(96, 5, 2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2))

model.add(Conv2D(96, 5, 2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1496, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: What code have you written? Have you tried using Keras already?

Comment: i have only written code for model not to train or test, so i want to know how to give image as input to above model. i can post model code if needed.

Comment: You need to provide some code, else the questions is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working example based on your data (as I assume from your info)

I have using the label as a vector of 1 and 0 e.g `[1,0,1,1,...]` 1 for figure region and 0 for none figure region, for a total of 1496 regions

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1337)  # for reproducibility

from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from keras.utils import np_utils

batch_size = 128
nb_epoch = 10
nb_regions = 1496

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 850, 1100

# create random test and train sets
X_train = np.random.randint(256, size=(10, img_rows, img_cols))
Y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(10, nb_regions))

X_test = np.random.randint(256, size=(10, img_rows, img_cols))
Y_test = np.random.randint(2, size=(10, nb_regions))


X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols)),
    Activation('relu'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(nb_regions),
    Activation('softmax'),
])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adadelta',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=nb_epoch,
          verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)

print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,
but in our case number of classes is 2
either its figure(1), or non figure(0)
and also in line 
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=mnsit.load_data()
we want our data to load which is image input, label as npy array

Comment: this is just an example, you should take it an adjust to fit your own case, if you can provide some of the data I may be able to help you...

Comment: my input is gray scale image with 850*1100 pixels
so if i have 10 images its a list of ten  850*1100 np array

Comment: changed my answer based on your new info about the problem

Comment: thank you for replying, but you are classifying whole image as either 0 or 1. but in my model i have final layer with 1496 filters which means i want my(44*34=1496) regions of images to be classified as 0 or one. the y_test and y_train data consists of 1496 values of 0s and 1s for each image. Hence I am concerned with classifying part of image(25*25 for each part in total of 1496 parts) into either 0 or 1. please help ASAP; Thanks in advance

Comment: i have edited my code in qtn about input and o/p shape

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. We implemented my model(as given in qtn) on set of some 26 images, thanks to your help, i have one further question, on running my accuracy was still on 0.0 after 25 epochs but error was reduced to approx 0.23. i dont think model is incorrect since it is the model structure took from the paper who has already implemented it. what could probably be wrong! thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the network is a big one and should run for longer than 25 epochs till will be able to produce a good classifier, also should get a lot of training data, I suggest using approaches to generate new data by manipulation of exiting images e.g jitter, distortion, scale, rotate and such...

Comment: I ran my model for 2250 images and for 20 epochs... It ran 20 epochs and then it just displayed memory error for evaluating my model. i.e after 20 epochs when it enocountered evaluate line in my program( ihave split 2250:90 - 10 for train test ) it crashed saying memory leakge. I am running it on nvidia 940 mx 4 gb of graphic memory.